# GDALTranslate output has not Coordinate Reference System when chunking raster C++

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdal-translate, c++

I am trying to take a chunk from a raster file using the GDAL library in C++. Here is the code I am using:

```
const char * inputFile = "water_mask.img";

auto *dataset = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(inputFile, GA_ReadOnly);

char *srsWkt = nullptr;
dataset->GetSpatialRef()->exportToWkt(&srsWkt);

const char *strOptions[] = {
        "-srcwin",
        "0",
        "0",
        "100",
        "100",
        "-a_srs",
        srsWkt,
        nullptr
};


GDALTranslateOptions *trOptions = GDALTranslateOptionsNew((char **) strOptions, nullptr);

int *err;
GDALDatasetH outH = GDALTranslate("gdal_tr_1.img", dataset, trOptions, err);
```

When checking the output in QGIS this is what I see:

[image: Image of QGIS]

Here is what the srsWkt looks like that I am passing as an arg:

```
PROJCS["Albers Conical Equal Area",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

and I have logged the `err` variable to make sure that is it `0`, which it is.

I am aware that this code has some memory leaks at the moment, that is not really my concern here.

EDIT: Forgot to add the `trOptions` line in the code block.

Comment: you set the srs to NULL (`srsWkt = nullptr`). and that is what you seem to be getting. Why would you expect something else?

Comment: @RobertHijmans In the line under it we are assigning srsWkt using the exportToWkt function. Also I posted what srsWkt is being logged as in the terminal in the original post.

Comment: sorry, of course.